# Statistics are not aligned properly on the SE 'About' page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-exchange, statistics

The grid items on the *Stack Overflow Stats* section of the [Stack Exchange 'About' page](https://stackexchange.com/about) are not aligned properly.

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

Would it be an idea to change it to look like this?

[image]

Is this by design or a bug?

I'm using Firefox on macOS, and the error occurs in all screen sizes.

Comment: Seems fine here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckvAF.png (Chrome on Windows). What OS/browser are you using? Screen size might be another culprit (I notice that on my end the word "Talent" doesn't drop to the second line), but I can't repro just by resizing the window.

Comment: @AdamLear Thanks for asking. I have updated my post.

Comment: Thanks! Hmm - still no repro on my end.

Comment: @AdamLear Hmm, strange. I'm using version 71.0, if that helps. Maybe it's because you're on Windows and I'm on MacOS.

Comment: Reproed on macOS 10.14.6 running FF 68.3.0 esr on MBA 2019

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed, quite soon after the report already, judging from [this February 2020 Wayback Machine snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20200201071454/https://stackexchange.com/about):

[image]

(verified with a couple of browsers on macOS, quite likely some CSS change accidentally solved this)